# Copying code from Visual Studio to Microsoft Word or to StackOverflow is indented too far to the right

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Whenever I copy code from Visual Studio 2010 to anywhere like Stack Overflow or into a Microsoft Word document or into the editor in Outlook, except for the first line of code, the rest of all the code is indented so far to the right and I have to constantly remove the tabs in each line before posting.

How do I get around this? There surely is a Visual Studio setting in the Edit menu that I have forgotten to use over the years.

**UPDATE**

In response to Akshay's answer, it appears that I already have that set to "Insert Spaces." Please see picture attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to replace tabs with a fixed number of spaces. In Visual Studio, go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor

Then choose the language you want to modify, or "All Languages" and select the "Tabs" option. This will let you replace tabs with the desired number of spaces.

Comment: That problem did not go away yesterday, but today, I re-started Visual Studio and it went away. Thank you. :-)

I guess it requires a new VS session for those changes to take place.

Answer (score 0):

**The Visual Studio Extension [Copy for review](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d17a777-0964-47e3-a6e5-3eed5b31ea93) may help you** (only for Visual Studio 2013 currently, however.)

It currently supports two output formats, both removing leading whitespace, while keeping the indentation as much as possible. Thus, this may improve your experience, together with the tip from Akshay.

*Disclosure: I am the author of that Extension. Please notfiy me, if I can improve it to your needs.*